# Syntax and design pattern of .MSF

Tags: syntax, cobol, file-type, mainframe

Currently i have to deal with .MSF file but i don't have idea about that type file after digging in google i have found it is used in Mainframe probably for message
Please suggest me proper link to get through knowledge about syntax and pattern of this type file.
Quick help will be appreciated.

**Note:** actually i want to parse that file and want to include needed info in a table so i need to guess which information is particular is need full and where

Comment: Why do you conclude that your mystery file is used for "screen design, encryption, message etc"?  The first hits I found refer to a [Mail Summary File](http://filext.com/file-extension/MSF) format.  Please add an excerpt from one of your mystery files to your question.

Comment: What does this have to do with COBOL or Mainframe? Try looking up [MORK](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mork)

Comment: MSF also stands for Sun Mainframe Security Facility.  There are various [configuration files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19065-01/servers.15k/816-5327-11/adminesm.html#83525), but they don't use a .msf extension.

Comment: basically it is used for message input output e.g. mid & mod format a bit extra information n syntax information i needed. And how a .MSF file can be referenced by its Cobol file.

Comment: yes it is cobol projects MFS file for input and output messages.

Answer (score 1):

MFS stands for Message Formatting Service (or Services).  It's a component of IBM's [IMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Management_System) hierarchical database.  It used to be called IMS DC.

This 300 page [IMS Primer](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245352.pdf) should help you get started with understanding IMS.